# Repeating same database query returns incremental results

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

In a long-running while loop, I'm trying to check the 1st record that matches my criteria in order to carry out actions upon it. The filter aspect of the query has been removed from my code below just for simplicity reasons, either way, I get the same issue).

In the following piece of code:

```
 while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    item = Session.query(Model).order_by(Model.id.asc()).first()
    print(f'Item id: {item.id}')
```

What I want to achieve as output is this:

```
Item id: 1
Item id: 1
Item id: 1
```

What I'm getting instead is this:

```
Item id: 1
Item id: 2
Item id: 3
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why it's moving on to the NEXT record when I'm not even doing any updates to the table data. I'm not even sure what term to search for in Google to try to solve this...

I've tried using `flush()` on the `Session` but that doesn't appear to make any difference.

In case it matters, these are the imports I'm using are:

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import os, time, sys
```

**UPDATE:**

Update on what I've discovered so far:
It's actually a combination of 2 things that make this happen:

- filter_by(status=0)
- item.status = 1

Adding the filter to the query and then trying to update the record status column for example (regardless of whether I actually commit the result to the DB or not)

So if I take out either of these 2 items then it works fine... but I need them!

```
def main():
    while True:
        item = Session.query(Queue).order_by(Queue.id.asc()).filter_by(status=0).first()
        if item:
            try:
                item.status = 1
                # Session.commit()
                print(f'Item id: {item.id}')
            except:
                print('error')
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], stressing reproducible.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I've added the actual function that gets called with some additional findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, although I'm yet to read up on exactly WHY it behaves like this, at least now I have finally found out what I need to do to solve the problem:

Once the query in each iteration has fulfilled its purpose (in my case, get the 1st record out of the DB that needs to be processed and then process it), I then needed to call the following: `session.expire_all()` and that fixed my issue.

So in my example above, it should now look like this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        item = Session.query(Queue).order_by(Queue.id.asc()).filter_by(status=0).first()
        if item:
            try:
                item.status = 1
                Session.commit()
                print(f'Item id: {item.id}')
                Session.expire_all() # <---- Add this line
            except:
                print('error')
        time.sleep(2)
```

This is the section in the SQLAlchemy docs that points roughly in this direction:
[SQLAlchemy - Refreshing / Expiring](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_state_management.html#refreshing-expiring)